# I have the following code about the current date and time so, how do I add day in current time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

```
<script>
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();    
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
</script>
```

Comment: Please use the title as a short description of your issue. Use the body of the question to provide details, your code, and any error messages encountered. Also please verify your tags prior to posting. This appears to have no relation to `PHP`, `CSS`, `mysql`, or `HTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

One day equals 24h = 24 * 60 minutes = 24 * 60 * 60 seconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 miliseconds

Edit: I might have misunderstood the question, but if what you want to achieve is adding 1 day to your variable, this will work.

Comment: _“One day equals 24h = 24 * 60 minutes”_ - no, it doesn’t. Not in countries that observe some form of summer/winter time.

Comment: @CBroe Could you please explain more detailedly? I'm not quite sure if that's possible.

Comment: The clock gets moved one hour (usually) forward or back, when countries switch between summer and winter time. So in those countries, there are two days, that do not have 24 hours then - they have 23, and 25, respectively. Now if you are in a situation where accuracy to the hour level matters, you can easily get in trouble by adding a fixed amount of (milli-)seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use toLocaleString() Date method to get that format

```js
let actualDate = new Date().toLocaleString();           // Output: d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss
console.log(actualDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking for the day of the week, then `today.getDay()` will return a numerical day of the week from 0-6. You could then use an array with the day names in to refer to the text for the day of the week.

For example:

```
var days = [“Monday”, “Tuesday”, “Wednesday”, “Thursday”, “Friday”, “Saturday”, “Sunday”];

var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+’-‘+today.getDate()+’-‘+days[today.getDay()];
```

Answer (score 1):

A `nextDay` function...

```
const nextDay = () => { return new Date(parseInt(new Date().getTime()) + 60*60*24*1000).toLocaleString() };
```

```js
const nextDay = () => { return new Date(parseInt(new Date().getTime()) + 60*60*24*1000).toLocaleString() };
console.log(nextDay());
```